# 500 - Internal server error. How to display detailed error on live website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

My live website is returning this error message when i browse it.

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I tried changing url to other specific page under that website and still returning same error.
In my local, it is working fine though. Is there a way to view this error in a detailed way. I saw some suggestions that will view the detailed error but it will work only locally which is i dont need because locally it is working fine for me.

I need to view this error in detailed way so can anybody suggest on what should I add or do?

Comment: Under the `<System.Web>` node place this `<customErrors mode="Off" />`. This will display the actual error that you see when debugging.

Comment: IIS has a setting to show only detailed error messages locally and you might change that to achieve what you wanted, but mind you that it is a risk to expose detailed error messages to remote users, as those pages contain way too much information.

Answer (score 0):

If you already updated your site and still you are getting the error, then try to clear your browser cache and run again. Its worked for me. :)